# How do pilots refer to an aeronautical/aviation chart in casual terms?

Tags: navigation, terminology, aeronautical-charts

How do you refer casually to an aeronautical chart? For example, in casual conversation between pilots and/or other related personnel, do you say the entire phrase? Or is it just something like "chart"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- For an Instrument approach chart:"**Approach Plate/Chart**."
- For an IFR Enroute chart: "**Enroute Chart**."
- For a Standard Instrument Arrival Chart: "**STAR**."
- For a Standard Instrument Departure Chart: "**SID**."
- For an Airport Taxi Diagram: "**Taxi** **Diagram**" or "**Airport Diagram**."
- For a Visual (VFR) Sectional Chart: "**Sectional**."
- For a Terminal Area Chart (TAC): "**Terminal Area Chart**."

There might be more, but these are common terms used.

Comment: Agreed.  I think collectively, the most generalized term would be "charts" when used to refer to multiple products, like "check to make sure your charts are up to date."  It's worth pointing out to anyone that isn't a pilot just how common the actual term used for them collectively is "my iPad."

Comment: BTW, it was very hard at my age to not answer "I refer to my charts with reading glasses, that's how."

Answer (score 6):

Just Aeronautical Chart, or Map. Maybe Aviation Chart or Map if the syllable count is annoying to you.

When I was bush flying, we didn't even use Aeronautical Charts; we used Topographical Maps made by the Ontario Ministry of Natural Resources, because the 1:50,000 scale was necessary to be able to scud run from lake to lake at 400 ft AGL under a 600 ft ceiling.

Answer (score 4):

The standard colloquial terms in the UK are "half mil" (1:500000) and "quarter mil" (1:250000).  See, for example [this page](http://woodair.net/Flight_Sim/tutorial/FST_Maps.htm), second paragraph of the "What do I need?" section.